# Display binary representation of decimal in mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am working on a project in my Computer Organization and architecture course.

They program asks the user for an integer number then print it’ binary form and vice-versa.

How do i accomplish this?
Is by dividing or shifting
I do not know where to start

Thanks

I tried division but it requires an array to store and print and looping

Comment: Possible duplicates: [MIPS Assembly converting integer to binary and reading the number of 1's?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71405216) / [MIPS/ MARS: Printing in Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77119954) / [Displaying number in Binary by shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12794387)

Comment: Once the number is in the computer as a number it is no longer decimal, hex, binary, or other, just a number.  So, there's two kinds of conversions, then, from string form e.g. text (hex, binary, decimal) to numeric and from numeric to string form e.g. text (hex, binary, decimal, etc..)